# Python how to use defaultdict fromkeys to generate a dictionary with predefined keys and empty lists

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict.fromkeys(['a','b','c'], list)
result['a'].append(1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-6c01c8d56a42> in <module>()
----> 1 result['a'].append('1')

TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'str'
```

I don't understand the error message, what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You don't do it that way is the answer...

Comment: @dawg could you explain the reason?

Comment: When you instantiate a defaultdict, you need to select a factory function. `.fromkeys` does not do that.

Comment: @dawg do you mind to post an answer and explain the right way to do it?

Comment: @Ben I tried it and you should see what happens after you do `result[a].append(1)`, all three keys reference to the same list which means all three lists will be appended with 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.fromkeys` [method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) is primarily used to set a dict to a single *same* default value:

```
>>> {}.fromkeys(['a','b','c'])
{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None}
```

It does not call a function for each key (which is what `list` or `[]` is).

[Default dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) needs a 'factory function' to be a default dict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result=defaultdict(list)
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
```

The factory function (in this case, `list`) is called any time a missing key is added to a defaultdict to form the default value.

So to set three lists with keys `'a','b','c'` you would do:

```
>>> for e in ('a','b','c'):
...    result[e]       # 'e' is not in the dict, so it is added 
                       #    and a new list is the value 
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []})
```

Or, you can use the `.update` method as Raymond Hettinger [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772414/298607):

```
>>> result=defaultdict(list)
>>> result.update((k,[]) for k in 'abc')
>>> result
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []})
```

Or, as `ivan_pozdeev` points out in comments, you can do:

```
>>> di=defaultdict(list,{k:[] for k in 'abc'})
>>> di
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []})
```

---

Or you can use a regular Python dict with a dict comprehension to get the same thing -- no defaultdict required -- if you only need or want those three keys with unique lists as their values:

```
>>> di={k:[] for k in 'abc'}
>>> di
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
```

And those are *separate* lists for each key:

```
>>> di['a'].append(1)
>>> di
{'a': [1], 'c': [], 'b': []}
```

A common mistake (which I have made ;-0) is to use something like `.fromkeys` and get the same list referred to by multiple keys:

```
>>> di2={}.fromkeys(['a','b','c'], [])
>>> di2
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}      # looks ok
>>> di2['a'].append('WRONG!')
>>> di2
{'a': ['WRONG!'], 'c': ['WRONG!'], 'b': ['WRONG!']}
```

Happens because the same single list is referred to by all the keys.

Comment: You forgot you can use the constructor to create the complete object in one expression: `collections.defaultdict(<default value generator unspecified by the OP>,{k:[] for k in 'abc'})`

Comment: The `.update` method is thus suboptimal: an additional unnecessary operation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, *fromkeys()* is for setting the *same* value over and over again. It isn't helpful when you need distinct lists.

So, I would tackle the problem like this:

```
>>> keys = ['barry', 'tim', 'fredrik', 'alex']

>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d.update((k, []) for k in keys)
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'barry': [], 'tim': [], 'fredrik': [], 'alex': []})
```