# Counting in a python nested dictionary | fromkeys() function How it works?

Tags: python, dictionary, count, increment, fromkeys

Given a list of runs up to a maximum reached stage, I would like to transfer the maximum values to a nested dictionary holding the number of **tries (t)** for **each stage.**

This means runs of 3, 4 and 7 should yield:

```
{0: {'t': 3}, 1: {'t': 3}, 2: {'t': 3}, 3: {'t': 2}, 4: {'t': 1}, 5: {'t': 1}, 6: {'t': 1}}
```

Stages 0,1,2 has been played for 3 times each, stage 3 for 2 times and stages 4, 5 and 6 only once.

- I Get instead the following result:

  ```
  {0: {'t': 14}, 1: {'t': 14}, 2: {'t': 14}, 3: {'t': 14}, 4: {'t': 14}, 5: {'t': 14}, 6: {'t': 14}}
  ```

### Source Code

```
p = {}
p = dict.fromkeys(range(7), {})

runs = (3, 4, 7)

for r in runs:
    for l in range(r):
        if "t" in p[l]:
          p[l]["t"] += 1
        else:
          p[l]["t"] = 1
```

**Why are the values the same in all the dictionary's key?**

Comment: The documentation for [dict.fromkeys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) says they share the same value. So the empty dict you pass in, `{}`, is shared between them all.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43772300/1084416

Answer (score 1):

That is because `dict.fromkeys()` sets the same object for each key in p

Try doing something like this instead

```
p = { i : {} for i in range(7) }

runs = (3, 4, 7)

for r in runs:
    for l in range(r):
        if "t" in p[l]:
          p[l]["t"] += 1
        else:
          p[l]["t"] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use a [Dict Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507637/13903942)

  ```
   p = {n:{} for n in range(7)}
    runs = (3, 4, 7)

    for r in runs:
        for l in range(r):
            if "t" in p[l]:
                p[l]["t"] += 1
            else:
                p[l]["t"] = 1
    print(p)
  ```

`fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value defaults to None.

All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally **doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list**.

To get distinct values, use a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dict) instead.

---

### Edit

Worth to mention:

- Use [setdefault Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_setdefault.asp):

  ```
   for r in runs:
            for l in range(r):
                if "t" in p[l]:
                    p[l]['t'] += 1
                else:
                    p[l].setdefault('t', 1)
  ```
- Pre-Build the Dict with the Key 't' in it.

  ```
    p = {n: {'t': 0} for n in range(7)}
    runs = (3, 4, 7)

    for l in range(len(runs)):
        for run in range(runs[l]):
            p[run]['t'] += 1
  ```